# PHP - Phar file with file operations can't access files

Tags: php, file, permissions, phar

I'm testing with Phar files and I generated a Phar from a project. The Phar file includes a class that performs a `file_exists`. When I instantiate that class from the Phar it always returns me `false`. Phar is unable to read files. I tried the same with source files without generating the Phar and it can read the file. What is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not that it cant read files, its that the path to the file is different. Are you trying to read a file outside the phar or a file inside?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015539/phar-archive-no-read-and-write-permissions-with-symfony-filesystem/48015791#48015791

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's a file outside the phar. Located in the same directory.

Comment: See linked answer, don't forget to upvote ;p You essentially need to do `dirname(Phar::running(false))` to get base directory from where the phar is running from, see docs: http://php.net/manual/en/phar.running.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Genius! Thank you, that solved the issue.

Comment: np, glad to help